# When is Non-Stochastic Global Optimization Preferable or Necessary?

Tags: optimization

## Background

I'm specifically referring to non-convex black-box optimization problems of the form:

$ \text{min} f(\vec{x})$

$s.t. \ \ a_i\le x_i \le b_i \ \forall i\in \{1,2,...,n\} \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \vec{a},\vec{b}\in \Bbb{R}^n $

Assume any $n$

Of interest are global optimizers that yield good solutions, but the solutions are not necessarily nor provably the global optimum.

#### Evolutionary Algorithms

Evolutionary algorithms (EAs) are often the go-to optimizers for these types of problems; such methods include: genetic algorithms, particle swarm optimizers, differential evolution, and all the algorithms based on organismal interactions. Pretty much every EA has stochastic components. Whether it's random initialization, or stochasticism in inter-generational (or intra-generational) subroutines such as selection for crossover or random mutations, stochasticism is pretty ubiquitous in the realm of EAs. Almost everything you'd find in [this journal](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4235) or [this one](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/swarm-and-evolutionary-computation/) would fall under this category.

#### Non-Stochastic Optimization vs. Deterministic Global Optimization

I am not interested in [deterministic global optimizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_global_optimization). Such methods provide some form of probability/confidence or even guarantee that the found solution is indeed the global optimum. These are more commonly seen in discrete/combinatorial optimization, but occassionally [some deterministic optimizers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11590-019-01421-0) become tangentially related when the user has some form of a priori knowledge/assumptions. The preference/necessity of deterministic optimizers is clear, even when they just give associated confidence with the solutions they find. So again, I am not referring to these.

#### Non-Stochastic Global Optimizers

I only know of a few non-stochastic global optimizers. Probably the most famous are the many variants of direct search (also called pattern search) algorithms. Conceived by [Fermi and Metropolis](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4377177), then popularized by [Hooke and Jeeves](https://doi.org/10.1145/321062.321069), and extended to a [generalized pattern search (GPS)](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a322273.pdf) making heavy [use of positive bases](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372648) as meshes, the direct search algorithms are similar to the classic [Nelder-Mead method](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-abstract/7/4/308/354237?redirectedFrom=fulltext) in that they use a neighborhood of points with an underlying geometric structure to (deterministically) explore the search space. Of course some non-stochastic variants exist as well, including [Luus-Jaakola](https://doi.org/10.1002/aic.690190413)'s sampling of a uniformly distributed neighborhood or the more popular [mesh adaptive direct search (MADS)](https://doi.org/10.1137/040603371) and all of its spin-offs.

There are some other non-stochastic global optimizers hiding out there on the internet, like [this one](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/785513), but I have yet to find one that explains the practical significance of the non-stochasticism.

---

## Question

What are some concrete use-cases for a non-stochastic global optimizer as described in the above-mentioned background?

Are there situations where non-stochastic optimization is *necessary*? Possibly mission-critical optimization, or where you need repeatability? Maybe something medically-oriented? Or for interpretability?

The only example I can think of (coming from an ML/DL background) is a situation where it would be slightly preferred, but certainly not necessary. In particular, we could train an ML model using a non-stochastic optimization algorithm, which would let us observe the effects of the ML model hyperparameters. In other words, eliminating the stochasticism in the optimizer could help interpret/tune the actual ML model hyperparameters as you'd be able to see causes/effects of modifications, where currently there's uncertainty due to the randomness involved in training.

Answer (score 0):

Non-stochastic global optimization could be practical for the directed search of the solution space. If there is a priori knowledge, that knowledge can direct the optimization to specific regions. Stochastic global optimization might explore inefficiently explore regions of the solution space.

A specific example of non-stochastic global optimization is [Bayesian optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization). In Bayesian optimization, samples are not picked at random. Samples are picked based the calculated posterior distribution, often to maximize the expected improvement.

Bayesian optimization has been used in [many applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization#Applications), including [machine learning hyperparameter tuning](https://distill.pub/2020/bayesian-optimization/).

Comment: Thanks @BrianSpiering. I'm familiar with Bayesian optimization (I should've included it in the background info). Are there cases where the non-stochasticism itself is essential for solving problems? Also, could you explain why and how stochastic methods cannot be "directed" via a priori (or even a posteriori) knowledge? Are there concrete examples that you could give to show a "directed" search that benefits from (or relies on) non-stochasticism? I'm looking for problems to which people might say, "we can't use stochastic methods here because X".